# HTC sensation XL android 2.3.5 infinite download process of any app

Tags: google-play-store, htc, htc-sensation

Friend of mine gave me HTC sensation XL with android 2.3.5 and asked one question: why I can't install any app from market?

I understand that device and adroid version are old enough for mid of 2016. But I can not find out what is exact problem. I've tried to clear cache/data/etc of market app and etc hundred times but no luck. Market doesn't say that your device is incompatible or doesn't support anymore, just stucking on download process. Otherwise some "base" apps were updated normally. Also I've tried to download some data directly from browser and it was ok.

So, all I want a small message that I own old piece of... hardware.

Answer (score 0):

Please do the following steps

> First check you have sufficient storage, under settings>>storage
>   remove your google account and add it again

please let me know the progress

Comment: I've tried it several times.

Comment: Could please mention the error message or exact response / behavior when you are trying to download also mention the play store version

Comment: It stucks on download progress with "starting download..." label and nothing happens. But UI still can response, I mean I can quit from market and continue to use cell phone.

Comment: Are you connecting with Wifi/Mobile network?

Comment: Connecting with Wifi